# Modify value of data in Orange

Tags: orange

I am new to Orange and it seems very useful for conducting exploratory data analysis.

One question I have is - can we use a widget to modify some values in the dataset?

For example, several numerical columns have some values of 0 which does not make sense and should be a "missing data". I do not want to ignore the line as some other column data are important. Also not all 0 should be replaced with "missing data" as for some column, a 0 is a valid data.
Can we do that with a widget? I could not figure it.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using a Feature Constructor widget with some conditional logic. For example, if looking at the Titanic survival data set, some fares are marked $0. This does not make sense since tickets have a non-zero value. You can create a new variable called fare_new where valid fares are copied over but 0 values are replaced with missing values. See screenshot below:

[image]